# How to make an executable script file without .bashrc

Tags: c, bash, terminal

I want to be able to activate a C program anywhere in the terminal without having to type the path to it. So instead of:

```
[some_text]:~ [username]$ ./[insert_c_executable]
```

or:

```
[some_text]:~ [username]$ Documents/Folder1/Folder2/.../[insert_c_executable]
```

That I can do something like this, like the programs `ls` or `pwd`:

```
[some_text]:~ [username]$ [some_cool_app_name]
```

I've seen a useful answer at the following link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-ran-from-termina/229592#229592?newreg=549425fc915d44d19a1e9be81f0172b7

However, neither .bashrc nor bash_profile are available on my home directory (on a Mac with OS X). I can't comment on that question since I don't have enough reputation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about using `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`?

Comment: Noticed that - bash_profile also doesn't seem to be present in my home directory. Only bash_history.

Comment: Why not create the files? Don't you have permission to write into your home directory?

Comment: As in create bash_profile or bashrc myself? Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mv path/to/your/executable_file /usr/local/bin/your_desied_command`

Example mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

Answer (score 1):

Best non-invasive way:

```
echo 'hash -p /path/to/executable executable' >> ~/.bashrc
```

This will add the command to your hashtable. However this means your not allowed to move the executable. (requires restarting of bash as the bashrc needs to be resourced).

Answer (score -2):

To any and all that come here:

I just moved the script file (doesn't need a .sh extension either with this route) to the bin directory (which is a directory in root). That does the trick.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to add comments like that, consider editing your answer, or (better) add a comment to your answer.

Comment: How is this not an answer to the problem exactly?

Comment: Actually you're right, I thought this would be a comment on @Cybersupernova s answer. I'll retrack my -1. However you should consider accepting his answer, as he suggested exactly what you did.

Comment: The correct approach is to create `~/.bash_profile` and set the PATH variable appropriately, not to put your executable in one of the system directories. There's no problem with creating the file if it doesn't already exist.